# Getting NameError in unittests for testing a parameter from argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x

I normally use Python for scripts but I am trying to write a unit test and am having a lot of issues. I would like to test a method that creates a parameter `--users`. The value is how many occurred.

```
count_users(df, args.metrics)
```

It is a spark dataframe and the metrics are set like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Processing args")
    parser.add_argument("--metrics", required=True)
    main(parser.parse_args())
```

The method looks like this:

```
def count_users(df, metrics):
    users = df.where(df.users > 0).count()
    temp_df = df.withColumn("user_count_values", F.lit(users))
    temp_df.write.json(metrics)
```

Now I am trying to write my test, and this is where I am not sure about:

```
def test_count_users(self):
    df = (
        SparkSession.builder.appName("test")
        .getOrCreate()
        .createDataFrame(
            data=[
                (Decimal(0),),
                (Decimal(22),),
            ],
            schema=StructType(
                [
                    StructField("users", DecimalType(38, 4), True),
                ]
            ),
        )
    )

        ap = argparse.ArgumentParser("Test args")
        ap.add_argument("metrics")
  
        args = {_.dest: _ for _ in ap._actions if isinstance(_, _StoreAction)}

        assert args.keys() == {"metrics"}

        count_users(df, args.metrics)

        self.assertTrue(args["metrics"], 1)
```

Right now I get an error that reads

```
 count_users(df, args.metrics)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'metrics'
```

Comment: The error is accurate: there is no variable named `args` defined in your `test_count_users` method. In fact, I don't see an `args` variable anywhere in the code you've presented here.

Comment: @larsks I updated the code and doesn't `parser.add_argument("--metrics", required=True)` add the metric? The code works but writing the unit test is my issue.

Comment: `args` is a dictionary (that you're building with that `{_.dest: _ for _ in ap._actions if isinstance(_, _StoreAction)}` transformation). A dictionary doesn't have a `metrics` attribute.

Comment: And yes, calling `parser.add_argument()` adds an argument to the parser, but you're never calling the `parse_args` method on the parser so you never receive a result with the argument values.

Comment: I'll be honest: I'm not really clear what you're trying to test in `test_count_users` or why you're bothering with `argparse` instead of just passing a static value to `count_users`. And I'm not entirely sure what `count_users` does, particularly because a regular DataFrame doesn't have a `.write.json()` method.

Comment: @larsks the df.write.json() is spark and I have to use it. I want to test the json that is being created, which is being mapped to an argument. If there is a better way I am open for suggestions. I have very little experience writing test cases in python

Comment: What is your overall goal of the `metrics` argument? Is it a flag, an output file name, something else?

Comment: @9769953 output name. Maybe I do not need to test the arg. I just need to test `temp_df.write.json(metrics)` where the json has a value of 1. How would you test `count_users`.

Comment: I would test `count_users` exactly as larsks mentions: provide it a fixed filename argument, then test that output. There is absolutely no need for command line arguments. Besides, these would likely be put as fixtures. If you want to test the *arguments* provided to a script, only then would you use e.g. argparse; and you would skip the whole `count_users` part, because that isn't part of the argument testing.

Comment: You might also read through the pytest documentation. There are lots of examples there, and useful pointers on how to do what. From what little code we can see here, it looks as if you're reinventing some wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with the `args = { ...` line, or the two asserts. Remove them, use something standard like

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Test args")
parser.add_argument("--metrics", required=True)

args = parser.parse_args(["--metrics", "output.json"])

count_users(df, args.metrics)
```

Your `args` variable won't have the appropriate attribute(s) *until* you parse the arguments. Of course, normally you'd call

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and let the user provide the `--metrics outputfilename.json` arguments to the script. The above is more for example or test use cases.